# Trigger color box from a tab link

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I have my index.html which loads content in a div using ajax as follow:

```
$('.item-101 a').click(function(e) {
    var url = $(this).attr('href') + '#maincontent';
    $('#maincontent-loader').html('loading...').load(url);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    $('.item-104, .item-109').addClass('hidden')
  });
```

And on the loaded content i am using a simple jquery tab as follow:

```
  $('#info div:not(:first)').hide();

  $('#info-nav li').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#info div').hide();
    $('#info-nav .current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var clicked = $(this).find('a:first').attr('href');
    $('#info ' + clicked).fadeIn('fast');
  }).eq(0).addClass('current');
```

All these are loaded from a script.js called in the header of my page.
On one of the tab content, i have a series of thumbnails which load their full size counter parts in a colorbox slideshow. Up to now all is working fine.
But i'm trigger the colorbox slideshow when i click my tab called "images". But i'm unable to make it work.
I tried to use the following as suggested on the colorbox site :http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq#faq-click using the following:

```
var $gallery = $("a[rel=gallery]").colorbox();
$("a#openGallery").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $gallery.eq(0).click();
});
```

Does anybody know what can be done to overcome this issue? My understanding is that it does not work because the tab title is already attached or bind to the tab script.
I'm still a bit new to jquery, i've been reading a lot and got a book, but it seems that it's beyond my ability.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: well i guess it's a jquery trick that i can't figure out. But i solved my issue using an agnostic tab script: http://nuevvo.com/labs/simpletabs/. Since it does not depends on any library, i was able to use the suggested script from colorbox to trigger my slideshow when clicking on the "image" tab.

Comment: well i spoke too soon. I have similar problem with the other script i use. I wonder if it's not coming from the way i load my content. So back to square one!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.click` with `.on`.

**Example**

```
$('.item-101 a').on('click',function(e) {
```

Comment: Thanks Dipesh but your suggestion is not working. It has no effect at all.